# shapeshift.io API: "Missing a Output Amount or Deposit Amount"

Tags: json, request

Using shapeshift api, posting to https://www.shapeshift.io/sendamount, I get this error: "Missing a Output Amount or Deposit Amount".

Request JSON String:
`{ "returnAddress" : "19z95ce8a1UwV3PCCCBE7AD7hNXENW3gu4", "withdrawal" : "0xFF7c7d21cf668F59A85188126D88106c62056Ec1", "pair" : "btc_eth", "amount" : "1" }`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I cleared this error in my case, by setting the 'Content-Type' header of the POST to 'application/json'.

Answer (score 0):

In my PHP case, instead of using a JSON string I went with a URL string and that cleared up the error.

For node.js or JavaScript, this worked for me with no issue:

```
    var settings = {
     "async": true,
     "crossDomain": true,
     "url": "https://shapeshift.io/sendamount",
     "method": "POST",
     "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     },
     "data": {
        "amount": ".002",
        "pair": "ltc_btc"
     }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
    });
```